# White space between upper and lower subfigure

Tags: spacing, graphics, subfloats

I am working on a paper right now. In this paper I have some figures, I am using subfigures for creating a page with two figures beside each other and one (bigger) figure beneath it. It is all clear and working very well but I prefer some white lines/space between the upper two figure and the lower figure. Now it is very 'crowded'.

Shall I add my LaTeX-code? I would do that but I do not know how. :-)

```
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{FTCS1.eps}
\caption{$\Delta{t}=10^{-2}$, $\Delta{x}=\frac{1}{10}$ en $\eqref{1/2} = 1$}
\label{fig:ftcs1}
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{FTCS2.eps}
\caption{$\Delta{t}=10^{-3}$, $\Delta{x}=\frac{1}{20}$ en $\eqref{1/2} \approx 0,4$}
\label{fig:ftcs2}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{2pc}
\begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.80\linewidth, height=10cm]{FTCS3.eps}
\caption{$\Delta{t}=10^{-4}$, $\Delta{x}=\frac{1}{80}$ en $\eqref{1/2} \approx 0,64$}
\label{fig:ftcs3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FTCS-benadering voor de warmtevergelijking met MatLab}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You **should** add a minimal code by pasting it into the editor window you used for your question ;-)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: put a blank line before `\vspace{2pc}` and possibly increase the value to `2cm` or whatever you need.

Comment: note you almost never want to do `[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]` it will distort the figure to force those dimensions. just specify _one_ of height or width.

Answer (score 2):

Put a blank line before

```
\vspace{2pc}
```

and possibly increase the value to 2cm or whatever you need.

Note you almost never want to do `[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]` it will distort the figure to force those dimensions. Just specify one of `height` or `width`

Comment: You could use `[width=0.9\linewidth,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]` to use the minimum of the two dimensions.